# Laravel Database SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having trouble connecting to database with my laravel project. Using docker and sail. I'm hosting a XAMPP MySQL database, on localhost, instead of the built in.

My .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=site_data
DB_USERNAME=dbUser
DB_PASSWORD=PassWord
```

The interesting thing is that the first migration attempt worked, and created the tables. But when I created an other migration, it refused to connect, and is still not connecting. Using TablePlus, given these credentials I can connect, and I see all the tables.

I've tried:
Restarting
Clearing cache, route, view, config
Rebuilding the whole sail, multiple times

Any ideas what could have happened?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check brew services list to make sure mysql isn't running (if you are using sail) if it is, you will need to stop it( or mariadb) and whatnot.  Yo will also need to make sure sail and docker-compose is exposing the port to your machine.  Last I knew, you used the DBHOST: thenameofthecontainer

Comment: Check that mysql in online maybe it encountered an error and runaway.
You can try to change the host name from 127.0.0.1 to localhost or the other way around

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be connecting to the wrong Database.
If in your env you need to connect to db which is hosted by docker, then you should follow next approach:
`docker ps -a`
it will list all of the available containers. You can reference do actual container name in your env. Just as an example:

```
DB_HOST=docker-mysql
DB_PORT=3306
```

In this case you need to specify port inside of the docker network :)

Could you specify your actual development env? Since i didnt get it based on the question.

You have XAMP - which is running and something in docker?